# Can't select from Excel spreadsheet when logon is via another server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a snippet of SQL that reads from an excel worksheet and updates a table in a database.

My issue is this.  Normally I use SSMS from my network login, it works great, I Log into our network server, and via that connection, connect to the Server where I have my databases.  So its a client using SSMS to connect to another server on the network.

When I say it works great that doesn't include a select statement against an Excel spreadsheet.  To get that to work I have to logon directly to the server containing my databases.  This is a nuances and I would prefer to avoid it.

Here is the select statement that works when connected directly to the server and doesn't work when logged in via our network.

```sql
 select * from 
  openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
   'Excel 12.0 Xml;Database=\\tsclient\C\Users\FRate.xlsx;',sheet1)
```

Here is the error I get when I execute the above statement from the client.

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have access to that UNC path?

Comment: not sure I totally understand what you're asking.  Do you mean does the server (name) where the database is have access to where the Excel file is stored?

Comment: No, does the service account, the account SQL Server is running under, have access to the UNC path the Excel file is located in?

Comment: Not sure, how can I tell?

Comment: I've been though this exact scenario recently and could not get it to work even though the SQL Server Service account had permissions to the file on the other server. Unfortunately SQL Server cannot pass on network login Kerberos credentials to another machine. I could  access files on another server where the file has permissions of the local login on the SQL Server machine. Or I could access files located on the SQL Server machine from a network login. But a network login could not access files on another machine via SQL Server. I'm all ears if anyone knows how to make it work.

Comment: @Galaxiom, Please let me know if you figure it out, and I'll do the same.  Very frustrating.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way around it. I also tried a Linked Server with every variation of the security settings. Most of them apply to server based logins and the ones that support domain logins return the same error as OPENROWSET.

Comment: I have not tested but I think this would work.

SQL Server Agent Jobs have a Run As property which could be set to a domain login with the permissions required to read the Excel file. The job would Execute a Stored Procedure that writes the Excel data to a table where it would then be available to the usual logins.

It could be run on demand. There is a whole suite of system procedures to modify and run Jobs.

The Stored Procedure could use dynamic sql to generalise it. Arguments would be passed through a table or by modifying the call in the job because Jobs run in their own session.